# Solving multiple inheritance in PHP without composition

Tags: php, structure, multiple-inheritance, composition

I'm working on a web app with Yii2 and PHP and am facing a typical multiple inheritance situation.

I have the classes `A` and `B` extend Yii2's `ActiveRecord` class since they represent relational data stored in a DB. But then I have class C, which doesn't (and shouldn't) extend `ActiveRecord` but shares common behaviors and member variables with `A` and `B`. In other words, the three classes genuinely share a common "is a" relation with a real-world entity, but only `A` and `B` are storable in a DB.

The way I've got things somewhat working until now is by using traits :

```
abstract class AbstractMotherClass extends ActiveRecord {
    use MyTrait;
}

class A extends AbstractMotherClass {}

class B extends AbstractMotherClass {}

class C {
    use MyTrait;
}

trait MyTrait {
    public $someVariableInherentToAllThreeClasses;

    public function someMethodInherentToAllThreeClasses() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then I have a method which can take any of the three classes (`A`, `B` or `C`) and work with it. Until now, I only had to throw `A` or `B` at it so I just wrote

```
public fonction someMethod(AbstractMotherClass $entity) {}
```

so I could get type hinting and other things in my IDE. But now I have to pass `C` as well and the app crashes since the method doesn't get its expected `AbstractMotherClass` instance if I call `someMethod(new C());`. To solve this, I would need a common class that all `A`, `B`, AND `C` could extend, so that I could type hint that class in my method. But that would be multiple inheritance since `A` and `B` must also extend `ActiveRecord` but `C` can't.

I've found a lot of multiple inheritance problems, but they all have been solved by changing the object structure, splitting responsibilities, using composition over inheritance, and so on. I couldn't manage to apply those solutions here as they didn't seem suitable nor practical, but I might be wrong.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Also if anyone has a better title suggestion, I'd be happy to change it (I couldn't find a good one).

Comment: Can you define an interface which MyTrait implements, and then `someMethod` can take an object of that type?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [Traits can't implement interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665978/why-php-trait-cant-implement-interfaces) and that [you can't type hint a Trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157586/php-type-hinting-traits). But maybe I didn't understand your comment well and you meant something like like @zzarbi below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Greg Schmidt mentioned as well, you could use interfaces

```
class ActiveRecord {

}

interface SameInterface {
    public function someMethodInherentToAllThreeClasses();
}

abstract class AbstractMotherClass extends ActiveRecord implements SameInterface{
    use MyTrait;
}

class A extends AbstractMotherClass {}

class B extends AbstractMotherClass {}

class C implements SameInterface{
    use MyTrait;
}

trait MyTrait {
    public $someVariableInherentToAllThreeClasses;

    public function someMethodInherentToAllThreeClasses() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

function foo(SameInterface $o) {
    return $o->someMethodInherentToAllThreeClasses().PHP_EOL;
}

echo foo(new C());
```

Granted you have to copy paste someMethodInherentToAllThreeClasses in the interface. Interfaces are usually used for solving some multiple inheritance problem.

Comment: That would do most of what I want, indeed. Thanks for the detailed exemple. However, I believe this won't give me autocompletion on the public variable defined in the Trait, would it ? This might not be that big of a deal, but I think it shows a design problem, since even the IDE isn't able to figure out what's being used. Not only must I go back to the Trait to check the exact syntax of the variable when I want to use it, but if I later want to rename it through refactoring tools, I will run into issues since the IDE won't be able to rename the call in your `foo` method.

Comment: Correct it won't give you autocompletion on the variable. But does the variable has to be public?

Comment: Well it's a variable that gets computed in another class since it's not really the classes' (`A`, `B` or `C`) job, then set in the instance, and then read from other places. So if I don't set the variable public, I guess I could write accessors, but I don't see the point if all I do is read and write the variable. Maybe there's another design problem here, but I didn't think so and I thought there was a way to achieve what I need while keeping the variable public.

Comment: @Scentle5S Then create setter and getter for this attribute and make them part of the interface?

Comment: Ok I'll go with that and accept the answer, thanks !